# Guide to Deploy React-Native App to App Store

Tags: ios, react-native, deployment

After all my research I am still unable to find a proper documentation for deployment of app in app store without using expo.

The application runs fine in debugging mode and other testing device the only problem being is deployment.

Thought I have already found an article called [Deploying a React Native App for iOS](https://medium.com/react-native-development/deploying-a-react-native-app-for-ios-pt-1-a79dfd15acb8) in medium but the problem is its incomplete and already outdated.

I already have setup environment in App Store . Please feel free to guide me I am willing to try any step.

Comment: AFAIK, You need XCode to upload the app to store, you should be able to generate XCode compatible project or, app from React Native, you can upload through XCode project, or through Application Loader for both you need to install XCode. Here is some [tutorials](https://codeburst.io/how-to-deploy-a-create-react-native-app-to-the-appstore-229a8fa36fb1)

Comment: *expo* is required to export *IPA* tell me what you get when you fire `exp build:ios` ?

Comment: Yes, sir I already have followed that tutorial too but that too uses expo . Is  there other way around expo for react-native project??

Comment: This is an old application and it dosnot have expo in it .
 When 'exp build:ios' shows 'command not found: expo' **_since expo is note there in project it self_**

Comment: I'm surprised that they don't have any documentation for this in the react-native documentation (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html).  It seems like it would be a pretty popular topic, however, perhaps not many people are deploying react native apps to app stores. This page (https://blog.appfigures.com/ios-developers-ship-less-apps-for-first-time/) indicates that only 1.85% of non native apps deployed to ios/android stores are react native.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Along with what is specified in the link that you shared.Follow the steps below:

1.Add app release certificates in Xcode configuration generated from Apple developer account.
2.Archive your project from menu options Product> Archive in Xcode.(This will generate an .ipa file)
3.Upload .ipa file generated to Itunes connect account.
4.Add ScreenShots and Submit it for Review.

Comment: Thanks man Let me try it . Hope it works. One more thing since the tutorial is old and using index.ios.js file instead of index,.js . Would that make a difference?

Comment: No it will not make any difference.In latest react native releases index.js is used instead of index.ios.js and index.android.js

Answer (score 5):

*As , a conclusion for my problem for now this is  the best combo guide that I would ever find in internet to deploy my app on App store  till now .*

1. [Wiki Genexus](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?34616,HowTo%3A%20Create%20an%20.ipa%20file%20from%20XCode)
2. [Blog Instabug](https://blog.instabug.com/2017/08/how-to-submit-app-to-app-store/)

*The problem in my case is I am not quite clear about the deploy process and there were too many guide to follow. Every guide I come across were either incomplete or some thing completely different. Please feel free to upload and review the links above.*

Thank you @Himanshu G and @JitenderBadoni

Answer (score 1):

I have 10 steps simple  to archive and upload app to AppStore:

1. Open file .env by VScode change env want to deploy (QA, UAT, PROD) default QA
2. Open app workspace
3. On Xcode choose TAGETS (app) -> choose tab General -> chose Identity -> change Build number
4. On Xcode (v12) set the active scheme -> select Any IOS Device(arm64)
5. Choose menu Product -> Archive -> waiting to archive
6. On Archives window -> select Distribute App button
7. Select method of distribution check App Store Connect -> click Next  -> choose Upload -> click Next then waiting analysis
8. Then tick all check box of App Store Connect distribution options -> click Next
9. On Re-sign app -> select Automatically manage signing -> click Next
10. Go to web App Store Connect -> choose tab TestFlight -> choose IOS and we will see the app we had uploaded.

Hope can help.