# Clarification on deployment workflow when want react-native apps published on native platform's app store?

Tags: react-native

Just looking for clarification about how react-native apps are intended to be deployed to a platform's native app store (as opposed to being downloaded 2nd-hand from the Expo app) from a continuous-workflow perspective (as opposed to [the mechanics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50823343/8236733) of it).

Looking at the expo docs for [standalone apps](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v34.0.0/distribution/building-standalone-apps/#7-update-your-app), it seems like the way a project would be continually (re)published would be to rebuild the app into the target platform and upload to the native platform's app store. Have not used react-native in some time, but I had initially thought that if you wanted to publish the app on a native platform's app store, you needed to *eject* the app and publish the platform's version of the ejected expo app to the native app store (and from then on, work on the app from the ejected version).

Could anyone with actual experience continually deploying react-native apps to native app stores enlighten me how what the standard workflow is here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expo provides a method for generating .ipa (iOS) or .apk (Android) without ejecting. You simply run `expo build:ios (or build:android)` to generate the standalone bundle which can be uploaded to the Play Store or App Store.

It is also worth noting that Expo provides internal over the air updates meaning you only need to publish your application to the App or Play store once. After the initial install, you can deploy updates through `expo publish`. Then, as per the [documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/configuring-ota-updates/):

> Expo will check for updates automatically when your app is
>   launched and will try to fetch the latest published version. If a new
>   bundle is available, Expo will attempt to download it before launching
>   the experience.